# RIP Terry Jones

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Terry Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Jones) - actor, writer, comedian, screenwriter, and director - has died just short of his 78th birthday. He was of course most famous for his work as part of Monty Python, starring in roles such as Mr Creosote and the mother of Brian the not-messiah, as well as directing the three films *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*, *Life of Brian*, and *The Meaning of Life*. He's only the second of the Monty Python troupe to depart, after Graham Chapman more than thirty years ago.

Comment: What's with all these brits kicking off of a sudden?

Comment: All I can picture is a giant foot stomping down...

Comment: @DavidW I'm a Brit too. Gonna watch out for giant feet in the sky.

Comment: http://www.montypython.com/news_terryjrip/504

Comment: @DavidW   Darling, you didn’t use tinned salmon did you?

Comment: I am flagging this record because it is scratched.

Comment: No no, he's... he's resting.

Comment: @MishaR Voom? This comedian wouldn't voom if you put four thousand volts through him! This is an ex comedian!